# How to decrease the number of classes in CIFAR-10

Tags: list-manipulation, image

I import the CIFAR-10 dataset to mathematica 11 notebook using code as below:

```
obj = ResourceObject["CIFAR-10"];
data = ResourceData[obj,"TrainingData"];
```

And then I get my whole dataset of labeled images which contains 10 classes of images (cat, dog, automobile, truck, etc.).

What I want to do is to decrease the number of classes in this dataset, which means I only want to use the images of cat and dog for my experiment.

I tried the approaches in the documents but they did not work.

Anyone can help me with this? I'm really appreciate for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Cases` for this together with `HoldPattern`

```
reducedSet = data // Cases[HoldPattern[ _ -> "dog" | "cat"]]
```

Comment: It works! Thank you sooooooooo much!